# why is it an infinite for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, infinite

I am trying to go through a for loop and it is just like any other for loop but it seems to be infinite; I must be doing something stupid. Can anyone see it?

```
double x;
for(x = -1; x < 1; x+=2/20) {
    double y = b * Math.sqrt(1-Math.pow(x-FocusToCenter, 2));
    System.out.println("X:"+x+" Y: "+roundFourDecimal(y));
}
```

And if  change x+=2/20, to x+=0.1 then it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Integer Division...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does `2/20` evaluate to ? I suspect since they're both integers, you're getting a 0, and hence not increasing `x` at all.

Trying expressing them as doubles e.g. `2.0 / 20.0`

Answer (score 2):

Integer Division , `2/20 = 0`

i.e. `x=x+0`

thus the iterator is not being modified and hence the infinite loop

To have work what you are trying to do, try `2.0/20.0`

Answer (score 1):

2/20 is integer arithmetic operation so result is zero. Basically you are not incrementing x in the loop. In order to thread this as float division you need this:

```
2.0/20
```

or

```
((double)2) / 20;
```